# SQL | Search a large string to return key-phrases found in table

Tags: sql, mariadb, expression

I have a table that has about 3000 different key-phrases (small strings). I need a query that takes the input of a large-string (like a large sentence or paragraph) and returns the records of key-phrases that exist inside the large-string.

Simplified example: Table has 5 records: "fishing", "pond", "cloud", "big one", "house".

Large-string input: "I have a pond at my house. I decided to go fishing and caught a big one."

Query outputs (matched records): pond, house, fishing, big one

Thank you,
James

I tried a few select statements to no avail. Maybe I need to parse the large-string into some kind of array before making a statement/query?

Comment: which databse system are you using?

Comment: For PostgreSQL you may use this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986491/sql-split-string-by-space-into-table-in-postgresql

Comment: For SQL Server I suggest using full text search https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Sorry I didn’t specify platform. I’m using mySQL with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

```
with small (term) as (
        select 'fishing'
  union select 'pond'
  union select 'cloud'
  union select 'big one'
  union select 'house'
)

select term
from small
where 'I have a pond at my house. I decided to go fishing and caught a big one.' 
  REGEXP concat('(^|.*[^a-z])', term, '([^a-z].*|$)') = 1
```

Comment: a 'cloudy', 'ponderous', 'housemate' would be a match

Comment: Good catch.  Thanks.  I updated my answer for that and for the new requirement that this is for MySQL

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately, it turns out the db is MariaDB, so I'm not able to use REGEXP_LIKE.

Comment: Please use correct tags including software version where possible.  If you can't tag the question with the right version number, state it in the question.

Comment: I updated my answer after spending about 20 seconds reading MariaDB docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FULLTEXT` index. No matter how large your string input is.

Then use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` 
WHERE MATCH(records) AGAINST ('"your large string"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance;
```

For more see these answers:

- [MySQL match() against() - order by relevance and column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259647/mysql-match-against-order-by-relevance-and-column)
- [MySQL MATCH() AGAINST() FULLTEXT Index - Achieve Partial String Match Combined with Phrase Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62843239/mysql-match-against-fulltext-index-achieve-partial-string-match-combined-w)
- [MySql `MATCH AGAINST` and `LIKE` combination to search for special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69870020/mysql-match-against-and-like-combination-to-search-for-special-characters)